# My MUI Link with Next.js 13 doesn't actually work in an IconButton

Tags: next.js, material-ui

```
// packages/webapp/src/app/(authenticated)/_components/Sidebar/index.tsx
"use client";
import React from 'react';
import { Box, Avatar, IconButton, Button, Stack } from '@mui/material';
import PaperContainer from '@/app/_components/PaperContainer';
import { usePathname, useRouter } from 'next/navigation'
import Link from 'next/link';

import QuestionAnswerIcon from '@mui/icons-material/QuestionAnswer';
import QuestionAnswerOutlinedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/QuestionAnswerOutlined';
import CloudSyncOutlined from '@mui/icons-material/CloudSyncOutlined';
import CloudSyncIcon from '@mui/icons-material/CloudSync';
import PeopleIcon from '@mui/icons-material/People';
import PeopleOutlineIcon from '@mui/icons-material/PeopleOutline';
import SettingsIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Settings';
import SettingsOutlinedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/SettingsOutlined';
import BarChartIcon from '@mui/icons-material/BarChart';
import BarChartOutlinedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/BarChartOutlined';


const navItems = [
  {
    href: '/insights',
    activeIcon: <BarChartIcon />,
    defaultIcon: <BarChartOutlinedIcon />,
    isActive: (pathname: string) => pathname.startsWith('/insights'),
  },
  {
    href: '/conversations',
    activeIcon: <QuestionAnswerIcon />,
    defaultIcon: <QuestionAnswerOutlinedIcon />,
    isActive: (pathname: string) => pathname.startsWith('/conversations'),
  },
  {
    href: '/data-connections',
    activeIcon: <CloudSyncIcon />,
    defaultIcon: <CloudSyncOutlined />,
    isActive: (pathname: string) => pathname === '/data-connections',
  },
  {
    href: '/people',
    activeIcon: <PeopleIcon />,
    defaultIcon: <PeopleOutlineIcon />,
    isActive: (pathname: string) => pathname === '/people',
  },
  {
    href: '/settings',
    activeIcon: <SettingsIcon />,
    defaultIcon: <SettingsOutlinedIcon />,
    isActive: (pathname: string) => pathname === '/settings',
  },
]

const Sidebar: React.FC = () => {
  const avatarUrl = '';
  const pathname = usePathname()
  const router = useRouter()

  const handleLogout = async () => {
    router.push('/auth')
  }

  return (
    <PaperContainer sx={{
      justifyContent: 'space-between',
    }}>
      <Box display={`flex`} flexDirection={`column`}>
        {navItems.map((item) => (
          <Link href={item.href} key={item.href} passHref>
            <IconButton color="primary" size='large'>
              {item.isActive(pathname) ? item.activeIcon : item.defaultIcon}
            </IconButton>
          </Link>
        ))}
      </Box>
      <Stack direction="column" spacing={2} alignItems={`center`}>
        <Avatar src={avatarUrl}>A</Avatar>
        <Button color="info" size='small' onClick={handleLogout}>Logout</Button>
      </Stack>
    </PaperContainer>
  );
};

export default Sidebar;
```

When I click on an icon button, it doesn't redirect. When I hover over, I see the URL. What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this isn't working? I've made a reproduction on [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/delicate-brook-2x5khh?file=/app/Sidebar.tsx:90,1) with your code and it works correctly for me.

Is it possible that you have another redirect elsewhere that immediately redirects you back to the page with the Sidebar? Or there could be something within the `PaperContainer` component which is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please wrap `Link` component with `IconButton`.

```js
<Box display={`flex`} flexDirection={`column`}>
  {navItems.map((item) => (
      <IconButton color="primary" size='large'>
          <Link href={item.href} key={item.href} passHref>
              {item.isActive(pathname) ? item.activeIcon : item.defaultIcon}
          </Link>
      </IconButton>
  ))}
</Box>
```